# How to end print that has multiple lines from cmd with python?

Tags: python, cmd

I have this code and it works:

```js
    print("YY YY", end="\r")
```

But when I to de the same thing with print that has many lines like this:

```js
         print("""
    yyy
    yyy
    yyy
    """, end="\r")
```

The end="\r" doesnt do anything.
How I can end that print the same way the first print?

Comment: Close the triple quotes right after the last character, i.e. `yyy""", end="\r")`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running this on Windows and you are wrongly expecting `"\r"` (which means carriage **r**eturn) to imply a linefeed, which in the Windows console it does not. All it does is move the cursor to the left edge of the screen. And you don't see that because the program then ends and you get a fresh command prompt.

If I modify your 1-line program like this:

```
from time import sleep
print("YY YY", end="\r")
sleep (2)
print("XX")
```

first I see

```
YY YY
```

with the cursor blinking under the first `Y` and then it changes to

```
XX YY
```

which illustrates what `\r` really does.

Change `end="\r"` to `end="\n"` and you will see the two blank lines after the last `yyy` that you seem to be expecting.

Though for sending output to the console, it would be better not to specify `end=` at all, because then you will get the default behaviour which is also what you expect.